# Listview with image different for each items

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I have a problem with my `ListView`:

The ListView item xml has a textarea and an Imageview, for each item taken from DB, I need to place a dedicated image (based on the _id).

Now I have this code which works (but without the images):

```
mio_db.openDataBase(); 
final Cursor data=mio_db.catalogo_prodotti();
final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mia_2); 
String[] from = new String[] {"prodotto","_id"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.nome_prodotto_lista,R.id.freccia_prodotto_lista};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.mia_lista_2, data, from, to); 
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For example, if my `_id` is 4 I need to put an image like `freccia_4` in the `R.id.freccia_prodotto_lista`

I don't know how to do it. I've read about custom adapter but I don't uderstand how to implement it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Below tutorial will help for your requirement **[Custom ListView](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) and [this](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)** Video - [youtubeVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjAlNfa6obU) Hope it helps

Comment: the problem is that the tutorials don't use a cursor to do that...

Comment: `SimpleCusorAdapter` constructor is deprecated.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html Better use the custom adapter. Following example http://www.androidchennai.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-listview-example.html

Comment: the problem is that the tutorials don't use a cursor to do that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109803/listview-with-image-different-for-each-items/12109951#comment16187659_12109951

Comment: you have linked my discussion :-|

Answer (score 0):

Creating CustomAdpter for your listview using cursor

**Step1**

[Follow this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

**Step2**

Instead of extending Array Adapter extend Cursor Adapter, it should work

```
class ListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
LayoutInflater mInflater;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;

RequestLogAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     //Get your details here
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                //Create layout for image with text here
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mulitcolumnlistview, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                //You can customise here

   }
 }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved in another way, maybe not the right one, but it works for now:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.prodotti);
    final Database_mio database_classe=new Database_mio(this); 
    database_classe.openDataBase(); 
    final Cursor data_mio=database_classe.catalogo_prodotti();
    ArrayList<Prodotto_per_lista> personList=new ArrayList<Prodotto_per_lista>();
    int prodotto=data_mio.getColumnIndex("prodotto");
    int id_immagine=data_mio.getColumnIndex("_id");
    while(data_mio.moveToNext()){
        switch(Integer.parseInt(data_mio.getString(id_immagine))){
            case 1:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_1,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 18:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_18,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 23:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_23,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 28:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_28,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 30:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_30,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 35:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_35,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 41:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_41,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 48:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_48,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 53:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_53,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
            case 57:
                personList.add(new Prodotto_per_lista(R.drawable.freccia_57,data_mio.getString(prodotto)));
                break;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    for(int i=0;i<personList.size();i++){
            Prodotto_per_lista p=personList.get(i);
            HashMap<String,Object> personMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
            personMap.put("name", p.getName());
            personMap.put("image", p.getPhotoRes());
            data.add(personMap);
    }
    String[] from={"name","image"};
    int[] to={R.id.nome_prodotto_lista,R.id.freccia_prodotto_lista};
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    data,
                    R.layout.mia_lista_2,
                    from,
                    to);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_mia_2)).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only problem now is that the id of the items is now taken from the array (data.add) instead of the _id from the database..